# XPath result with duplicates

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<centro>
  <contenidos>
    <contenido curso="1" value="a" />
    <contenido curso="1" value="b" />
    <contenido curso="1" value="c" />
    <contenido curso="1" value="d" />
  </contenidos>
</centro>
```

And the bellow XPath:

```
/centro/contenidos/contenido[@curso=1]
```

When I evaluate the XPath in `XML Copy Editor` program the results is:

```
<contenido curso="1" value="a"/>
<contenido curso="1" value="a"/><contenido curso="1" value="b"/>
<contenido curso="1" value="a"/><contenido curso="1" value="b"/><contenido curso="1" value="c"/>
<contenido curso="1" value="a"/><contenido curso="1" value="b"/><contenido curso="1" value="c"/><contenido curso="1" value="d"/>
```

I think it should return only the four elements, why it return this pyramid result? Is a problem with `XML Copy Editor` or the XPath?

Comment: yes, you're right. it's definitely not the correct match for the xpath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behaviour is not the expected one for sure, like you state it should simple return the four nodes and not an incremental concatenation of each of them.

Searching for `xpath` at the [XML Copy Editor bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/xml-copy-editor/bugs/search/?q=xpath), there's no reference to your problem, so my advise would be for you to submit that one yourself and wait/hope for it to be fixed in a new release shortly.

Comment: Ohh, ok. I have open a bug (https://sourceforge.net/p/xml-copy-editor/bugs/198/).

Comment: It have been accepted as a bug: "Thank you for reporting this bug. It will be fixed in the next release.", status: open-accepted, assigned_to: Zane U. Ji. So I will mark your answer as the correct one.