# With R and XML, can an XPath 1.0 expression eliminate duplicates in the content returned?

Tags: r, xpath, xml-parsing

When I extract content from the following URL, using XPath 1.0, the cities that are returned contain duplicates, starting with Birmingham.  (The complete set of values returned is more than 140, so I have truncated it.)  Is there a way with the XPath expression to avoid the duplicates?

```
require(XML)
doc <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.littler.com/locations", useInternal = TRUE)
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class = 'mm-location-usa']//a[position() < 12]", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)

 [1] "Birmingham"          "Mobile"              "Anchorage"           "Phoenix"             "Fayetteville"        "Fresno"             
 [7] "Irvine"              "L.A. - Century City" "L.A. - Downtown"     "Sacramento"          "San Diego"           "Birmingham"         
[13] "Mobile"              "Anchorage"           "Phoenix"             "Fayetteville"        "Fresno"              "Irvine"             
[19] "L.A. - Century City" "L.A. - Downtown"     "Sacramento"          "San Diego"
```

Is there an XPath expression or work around along the lines of [not-duplicate()]?

Also, various [position() < X] permutations don't produce only the cities and only one instance of each.  In fact, it's hard to figure out how positions are counted.

I would appreciate any guidance or finding out that the best I can do is limit the number of duplicates returned.

BTW [XPath result with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721060/xpath-result-with-duplicates) is not the same problem nor are the questions that pertain to duplicate nodes, e.g., [How do I identify duplicate nodes in XPath 1.0 using an XPathNavigator to evaluate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203117/how-do-i-identify-duplicate-nodes-in-xpath-1-0-using-an-xpathnavigator-to-evalua)

Comment: So the question boils down to, "Can you identify duplicates while you're assembling a list?" or something along those lines?

Comment: Yes, but as I noted in the comment to jhoward's answer, this is one of multiple sites, so I would like to build the expression in one call.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function for this, it is called `distinct-values()`, but unfortunately, it is only available in XPath 2.0. In R, you are limited to XPath 1.0.

What you can do is

```
//div[@class = 'mm-location-usa']//a[position() < 12 and not(normalize-space(.) = normalize-space(following::a))]
```

What it does, in plain English:

> Look for `div` elements, but only if their `class` attribute value equals "mm-location-usa". Look for descendant `a` element of those `div` elements, but only if the `a` element's position is less than 12 and if the normalized text content of that `a` element is not equal to the text content of an `a` element that follows.

But is is a computationally intensive approach and not the most elegant one. I recommend you take jlhoward's solution.

Comment: Nice solution. When I try this I get some duplicates, but along the same lines this xPath expression seems to work: `//div[@class = 'mm-location-usa']//a[position() < 12 and not(following::a=text())]`.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do it this way??

```
require(XML)
doc <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.littler.com/locations", useInternal = TRUE)
xPath <- "//div[@class = 'mm-location-usa']//a[position() < 12]"
unique(xpathSApply(doc, xPath, xmlValue, trim = TRUE))
#  [1] "Birmingham"          "Mobile"              "Anchorage"          
#  [4] "Phoenix"             "Fayetteville"        "Fresno"             
#  [7] "Irvine"              "L.A. - Century City" "L.A. - Downtown"    
# [10] "Sacramento"          "San Diego"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Good idea and it works on this single instance, but there are multiple sites and a large script to scrape them.  Is it possible to join the unique() call to the XPath call?  Maybe wrap the call in unique()?

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can just create an XPath to process the `li` tags in the first `div` (since they are duplicate `div`s):

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id='lmblocks-mega-menu---locations'][1]/
            div[@class='mm-location-usa']/
            ul/
            li[@class='mm-list-item']", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)

##  [1] "Birmingham"          "Mobile"              "Anchorage"          
##  [4] "Phoenix"             "Fayetteville"        "Fresno"             
##  [7] "Irvine"              "L.A. - Century City" "L.A. - Downtown"    
## [10] "Sacramento"          "San Diego"           "San Francisco"      
## [13] "San Jose"            "Santa Maria"         "Walnut Creek"       
## [16] "Denver"              "New Haven"           "Washington, DC"     
## [19] "Miami"               "Orlando"             "Atlanta"            
## [22] "Chicago"             "Indianapolis"        "Overland Park"      
## [25] "Lexington"           "Boston"              "Detroit"            
## [28] "Minneapolis"         "Kansas City"         "St. Louis"          
## [31] "Las Vegas"           "Reno"                "Newark"             
## [34] "Albuquerque"         "Long Island"         "New York"           
## [37] "Rochester"           "Charlotte"           "Cleveland"          
## [40] "Columbus"            "Portland"            "Philadelphia"       
## [43] "Pittsburgh"          "San Juan"            "Providence"         
## [46] "Columbia"            "Memphis"             "Nashville"          
## [49] "Dallas"              "Houston"             "Tysons Corner"      
## [52] "Seattle"             "Morgantown"          "Milwaukee"
```

I made an assumption here that you're going after US locations.